# reactjs and bootstrap columns not lining up

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Can someone please shed some light on this for me ... No matter what I do with the below code I always seem to have three columns but I just want two .. What I mean is the way the below shows on my page it is expecting another one to the right .. so it does not look like this

COL 1    ..... SPACE HERE........    COL 2

But instead

COL 1 COL 2

```
    <Row className="show-grid text-center">
      <Col xs={12} sm={4} className="person-wrapper">
        <Image src="assets/image.jpg" circle className="profile-pic"/>
        <h3></h3>
      <Link to="/place">
        <Button bsStyle="primary">click</Button>
      </Link>
      </Col>
      <Col xs={12} sm={4} className="person-wrapper">
        <Image src="assets/image1.jpg" circle className="profile-pic"/>
        <h3></h3>
      <Link to="/place">
        <Button bsStyle="primary">click</Button>
      </Link>
      </Col>
    </Row>
```

Comment: You've written I want COL1 COL2 But instead getting COL1 COL2 , okay so what's the difference?

Comment: sorry format was not correct .. I will edit

Comment: Try `sm={{ span: 4, offset: 4 }}` on the second `<Col>`. Source : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#responsive-grids Never used Bootstrap with ReactJS so I don't know if it'll work. Tell us if it works or not !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid contains 12 columns, not 8. Your two `sm` columns need to add up to 12. Use `sm={6}` instead of `sm={4}`

```
<Row className="show-grid text-center">
  <Col xs={12} sm={6} className="person-wrapper">
    <Image src="assets/image.jpg" circle className="profile-pic"/>
    <h3></h3>
  <Link to="/place">
    <Button bsStyle="primary">click</Button>
  </Link>
  </Col>
  <Col xs={12} sm={6} className="person-wrapper">
    <Image src="assets/image1.jpg" circle className="profile-pic"/>
    <h3></h3>
  <Link to="/place">
    <Button bsStyle="primary">click</Button>
  </Link>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set an offset to each "resolution" you want to cover, in your case for `sm`:

```
<Row className="show-grid text-center">
  <Col xs={12} sm={4} className="person-wrapper">
    {/* your content goes here */}
  </Col>
  <Col xs={12} sm={{ span: 4, offset: 4 }} className="person-wrapper">
    {/* your content goes here */}
  </Col>
</Row>
```